# haben gehabt - Möglichkeit ausdrücken oder sonst was?

Tags: subjunctive

ich habe gerade einen Artikel auf SZ gesehen, der Titel laut: „Wir haben Tage gehabt, da konnten wir kein neues Kind aufnehmen“. Ich frage mich, ob welche spezifische Bedeutung durch „haben gehabt“ vermittelt werden. Soweit ich weiß, konjunktiv I kann verwendet, um eine indirekte Rede einzuleiten. Man platziert den Satz hier aber in „“, macht mir deswegen indirekte Rede keinen Sinn. Habe ich eine andere Grammatikregel von Konjunktiv I verpasst?

Vielen Dank im Voraus!

Comment: Ich versteh die Frage nicht ganz, denn da ist kein Konjunktiv. *Wir haben gehabt* ist das gewöhnliche Perfekt (im Indikativ) des Verbs *haben*, so wie *wir haben gegessen/ geweint/ getan ...* bei *essen/ weinen/ tun ...*

Comment: Danke für deine Antwort! :-)

Answer (score 2):

In diesem Satz wird kein Konjunktiv verwendet. Was Dich möglicherweise irritiert, ist die Tatsache dass "haben" hier zweimal verwendet wird: Einmal als Hilfsverb und einmal als Vollverb.

> Wir haben Erbsen gegessen.

Hier wird "haben" als Hilfsverb verwendet, um die Vergangenheit auszudrücken.

> Wir haben (heute) einen anstrengenden Tag.

Hier wird "haben" als Vollverb verwendet.

Wenn wir dann beides kombinieren, bekommen wir zum Beispiel

> Wir haben letzten Dienstag einen anstrengenden Tag gehabt.

In Deinem Beispiel ist die nähere Beschreibung der Tage, die "wir" hatten, in einem Nebensatz platziert:

> Wir haben Tage gehabt, da...

Alternativ hätte man auch sagen können

> Wir haben Tage gehabt, an denen...

oder auch

> Wir hatten Tage, an denen...

Da der Satz in Anführungszeichen steht, wird es vermutlich ein wörtliches Zitat sein.

Noch als Randbemerkung: "*auf* einem Medium" wird üblicherweise für Websites verwendet. Bei einer (gedruckten) Zeitung verwendet man eher "in". Anstelle von "auf SZ" wäre also entweder "in der SZ" (Printausgabe) oder "auf sueddeutsche.de" klarer.

Comment: Es könnte zusätzlich noch helfen, Tempus und Modus der Konstruktion zu benennen: Perfekt Indikativ

Comment: Danke für Deine Aufklärung und auch die Randbemerkung. Perfekt hat mir am Anfang gar nicht aufgefallen. Persönlich bemerke ich, dass man einfach „hatten“ mit dem Verben haben benutzt und Perfekt eher für andere Verben oder?

Comment: @herbstlaub12 Im alltäglichen Sprachgebrauch wird generell oft das Perfekt verwendet, wo das Lehrbuch eigentlich (zum Beispiel) die einfache Vergangenheit vorsieht. Das hängt meistens nicht davon ab, welches Verb benutzt wird.

Comment: Danke Dir sehr :-)